# How does pythons code execution order work?

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I have defined a function in which I want a couple of lines of code to run before a for loop however, none of the code above the for statement run for some reason? But if I comment out the for loop then the code runs perfectly fine. I thought that the code would execute down in order but it seems to skip to the for loop. I think it may be something to do with my indentation, either way all help is appreciated. thanks :)

```
    def process_moves(replace_me):

#why is this code not run I want it to run this code AND THEN RUN THE FOR STATEMENT.
    turtle.setpos(-300,300)       
    turtle.write('TEST TEXT', align='left', font=20)

#Draw text in corners for each flag

    turtle.setpos(positions[0][:2])
    turtle.write('A', align='left', font=20)

    turtle.setpos(positions[1][:2])
    turtle.write('B', align='center', font=20)

    turtle.setpos(positions[2][:2])
    turtle.write('C', align='center', font=20)

    turtle.setpos(positions[3][:2])
    turtle.write('D', align='center', font=20)

screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle()

for competitor, direction in random_moves():

    if competitor == 'Competitor A':
        turtle.penup()
        if direction == 'Left':
            if positions[0][2] != 'A':
                positions[0][0] -= HORIZONTAL
                positions[0][2] = chr(ord(positions[0][2]) - 1)
        elif direction == 'Right':
            if positions[0][2] != 'G':
                positions[0][0] += HORIZONTAL
                positions[0][2] = chr(ord(positions[0][2]) + 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `def` keyword defines a python function, the code in the function is not run until you call the function. In your example I do not believe the `def` is nessecary at all.

```
screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle()

turtle.setpos(-300,300)       
turtle.write('TEST TEXT', align='left', font=20)

turtle.setpos(positions[0][:2])
turtle.write('A', align='left', font=20)

turtle.setpos(positions[1][:2])
turtle.write('B', align='center', font=20)

turtle.setpos(positions[2][:2])
turtle.write('C', align='center', font=20)

turtle.setpos(positions[3][:2])
turtle.write('D', align='center', font=20)

for competitor, direction in random_moves():

    if competitor == 'Competitor A':
        turtle.penup()
        if direction == 'Left':
            if positions[0][2] != 'A':
                positions[0][0] -= HORIZONTAL
                positions[0][2] = chr(ord(positions[0][2]) - 1)
        elif direction == 'Right':
            if positions[0][2] != 'G':
                positions[0][0] += HORIZONTAL
                positions[0][2] = chr(ord(positions[0][2]) + 1)
```

However, if you do wish to use the function the correct code would be as follows:

```
def process_moves():
    global turtle

    turtle.setpos(-300,300)       
    turtle.write('TEST TEXT', align='left', font=20)

    turtle.setpos(positions[0][:2])
    turtle.write('A', align='left', font=20)

    turtle.setpos(positions[1][:2])
    turtle.write('B', align='center', font=20)

    turtle.setpos(positions[2][:2])
    turtle.write('C', align='center', font=20)

    turtle.setpos(positions[3][:2])
    turtle.write('D', align='center', font=20)

screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle()

process_moves()

for competitor, direction in random_moves():

    if competitor == 'Competitor A':
        turtle.penup()
        if direction == 'Left':
            if positions[0][2] != 'A':
                positions[0][0] -= HORIZONTAL
                positions[0][2] = chr(ord(positions[0][2]) - 1)
        elif direction == 'Right':
            if positions[0][2] != 'G':
                positions[0][0] += HORIZONTAL
                positions[0][2] = chr(ord(positions[0][2]) + 1)
```

Both examples should have the same output, the main advantage to creating functions is reusability. If you are not going to use the function code more than once there is no point creating a function.

Comment: ah, legend. thanks im new to coding ofc I miss such a simple thing. I know its better etiquette and efficiency to use functions properly. will improve over time :)

Comment: Don't worry we've all been there, have fun on your coding adventure- feel free to accept my answer and upvote it if it did work as intended :)